# both block arg and actual block given (SyntaxError) in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and the following piece of code

```
self.class.send( :define_method, name , &block ){ name.call(name ,&block)}
```

is giving me   both block arg and actual block given (SyntaxError)

can someone help me and explain why this is coming?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove either the `&block` argument or `{ name.call(name ,&block)}{ name.call(name ,&block)}`.